# NightmareJS script execution error

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to run example code from NightmareJS documentation:

```
   var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
   nightmare = Nightmare();

    nightmare.goto('http://cnn.com')
      .evaluate(function(){
        return document.title;
      })
      .end()
      .then(function(title){
        console.log(title);
      })
```

> $node test.js

But node returns an error:

```
/home/user1/node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js:84
  this.queue((done) => {
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user1/test.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

What can cause such type of error? Could be old version of node?
Node version is v0.10.25.

Comment: Try to run node with the `--harmony` commandline option

Comment: same error with --harmony key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct: NodeJS did not include fat-arrow (`=>`) support until v0.12.x with `--harmony`.  Nightmare [recommends](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/blob/master/package.json#L49) v4.0.0 at a minimum.